# Why two same queries statements have different result

Tags: mysql

Here is my queries statement. They are similar but the result when execute is different. Both results are valid according to my ORDER BY clause. But the order in in `label_total` column is not same

--First SQL Statement

```
SELECT
    labels.production_line_id,
    prices.`code`,
    labels.quantity,
    `labels`.`total` AS `label_total` 
FROM
    `labels`
    INNER JOIN `order_details` ON `labels`.`order_detail_id` = `order_details`.`id` 
    AND `order_details`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
    INNER JOIN `prices` ON `prices`.`id` = `order_details`.`price_id` 
    AND `prices`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
WHERE
    `order_details`.`order_id` IN ( '2452' ) 
    AND `labels`.`type` = '0' 
    AND `labels`.`status` != '7' 
    AND `labels`.`status` != '8' 
ORDER BY
    `labels`.`production_line_id` ASC,
    `prices`.`code` ASC,
    `labels`.`quantity` DESC
```

-- Second

```
SELECT
    labels.production_line_id,
    prices.`code`,
    labels.quantity,
    `labels`.`total` AS `label_total` 
FROM
    `labels`
    INNER JOIN `order_details` ON `labels`.`order_detail_id` = `order_details`.`id` 
    AND `order_details`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
    INNER JOIN `prices` ON `prices`.`id` = `order_details`.`price_id` 
    AND `prices`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
WHERE
    `order_details`.`order_id` IN ( '2452' ) 
    AND `labels`.`type` = '0' 
    AND `labels`.`status` != '7' 
    AND `labels`.`status` != '8' 
ORDER BY
    labels.production_line_id ASC,
    prices.`code` ASC,
    labels.quantity DESC
```

The result

[image]

Comment: what do you mean with "addition field"  .?. the isre not column name addition in your queries

Comment: The second statement given above not only contains a syntax error (comma before `FROM` clause) so won't even execute, but furthermore appears to contain a logic error, where `IS NULL` is repeated in the criteria before the second `JOIN`.  It's pretty hard to guess at what might be the problem if the query you're showing us isn't even the one you're running...

Comment: @scaisEdge I updated question. The addition field is `labels.total`

Comment: @eggyal Sorry My bad i i  I updated question

Comment: You still have a syntax error in the second query due to the superfluous comma before the `FROM` keyword: did you mean to select another (total) column?  Anyway, both results adhere to the specified `ORDER BY` clause and MySQL makes no guarantee as to the order in which records of equal order will be returned (it is indeterminate by design); you will probably find that MySQL is selecting different indexes for use in the two queries—perhaps a covering index is available for one or both—and this is yielding a different sort order.  You could check each query's `EXPLAIN` plan for more detail.

Comment: @eggyal I have updated syntax error in the second query. I have used EXPLAIN to show information of both query, And the information is similar on both query exclude 'rows' column. Where could I find the resource/detail about this issue and how could I make two queries have same result

Comment: Okay, but now your second query cannot have produced the results shown in your screenshot (as it doesn't select a `total` column)!  Why not just paste exactly the query used to produce the results you're showing?  And as I said, subject to the `ORDER BY` being correctly satisfied (which it is in both cases) MySQL is free to return results sorted however it wants—it makes no guarantees that results will be consistent between queries or even between subsequent executions of the same query.  If you need results in a particular order, then you should specify it in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: For example, if you want the `total` column to be returned in descending order then you should add `, labels.total DESC` or whatever to the end of the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @eggyal Sorry my bad again. I updated again the queries statement and the screenshot also I changed the title of question too. Conclusion that is how's mysql works. Thank you for the explanation